# Obtaining 10.6 Base SDK for Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can I obtain and use 10.6 as base SDK in Xcode 4.5.2?

I downloaded Xcode 4.5.2 from the Mac App Store (through a link on the Apple developer site).

Is there a way I can somehow download the 10.6 SDK separately and start using it as a base SDK?

Strangely enough, I can download the **documentation** for the 10.6 SDK through Xcode's Preferences window, but not the SDK itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't download the 10.6 SDK separately.

Is there a reason you can't use the 10.8 or 10.7 SDK?

Keep in mind that just because you build against the 10.8 SDK, that doesn't mean you can't also have that built application work on 10.8, 10.7 and 10.6. (This is often a cause of confusion among new developers). You control backwards-compatibility through the `Deployment Target` setting like shown in the image below.

[image]

By default, the deployment target is generally set to the same version of OS X as the SDK is, but changing it to 10.6, for example, should allow it to run on a machine with OS X 10.6. (Of course, you should really test to make sure that's the case).

Comment: There may be reasons for really needing the 10.6 SDK, though it probably doesn't apply to the original poster, e.g., if you have legacy code that uses QuickDraw.

Comment: @JWWalker: yeah, I know about that but I'm pretty sure all Carbon-UI based stuff was removed by the 10.6 SDK. In other words, you'd need 10.5 SDK for that.

Comment: No, as a matter of fact, I am now using the 10.6 SDK to build some code with old QuickDraw bits.  Oh, and don't bunch all Carbon UI together; the newer HIView stuff is probably still in the 10.8 SDK, though not for 64-bit binaries.

Comment: Yup, lol, you're right. To be honest, that project I'm working on right there in the image, I actually have to use Xcode 3.2.6 to compile for 10.5 compatibility (Xcode 4.x & clang produces an incompatible executable for 10.5 in 64 bit mode). I was actually misremembering about the removal. All of the headers and stuff are there in 10.6 and later, it's just that Xcode 4.x has absolutely no documentation or templates for the Carbon UI stuff.

Comment: This may work. However, is there any way to get Xcode to warn me somehow if I use >= 10.7 API, even if my deployment target is 10.6? Or is my only option to just check manually whether each API I use is indeed supported on 10.6, and actually carefully test every feature of the app on 10.6? That second option would, of course, be rather tedious...

Comment: »While your app still works in 10.6 if linked against the 10.8 SDK this poses a great risk. If you use an Objective-C method not available in 10.6 you will get an exception when running your app on Snow Leopard. If you link against the 10.8 SDK you will NOT get a warning if the method you’re calling is not available in 10.6 Snow Leopard even if you’ve set the minimum deployment target to 10.6.« http://cocoadevblog.avisnocturna.com/2012/09/target-os-x-10-6-with-xcode-4-4-and-4-5/

Answer (score 3):

Download xcode with `MacOSX10.6.sdk`. Now copy `MacOSX10.6.sdk` inside /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs

Its also working fine with Xcode 5.0.

[image]

Comment: On Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.6, With new empty project it does not work. "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableOrderedSet", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libarclite_macosx.a(arclite.o). It works only if I set: 'Architectures 32-bit intel'. (with 'Build Active Architecture Only: NO'). Standard 32/64 bit Intel or 64 bit Intel does not compile. Is it normal?

Comment: I needed the Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7 SDKs, which I found in the package contents for XCode 4.3.3 for Lion. Thanks!